# Changing page size by Atlas in QGIS

Tags: qgis, printing, atlas

I have an Atlas with different zones in an area and I want to export them at the same scale. To do so I need different page sizes to export them while fitting in the page. I managed to add an automatic layout margin to the map but I don't know how to change page width and height by map extend. I want the maps to have the same scale ( 1:5000), to be defined by atlas and the page to be defined by map extent. Is this possible in QGIS?
The questions already on the forum only show how to align by map.

Comment: While referring to an older QGIS version this tutorial from Alexandre Neto should get you where you want (part-2 seem more relevant to you, part-3 doesn't seem to exist...) : https://gisunchained.wordpress.com/2014/11/09/series-de-mapas-com-formatos-multiplos-em-qgis-2-6-parte-1-multiple-format-map-series-using-qgis-2-6-part-1/